# best practice to test a runtime with large chain state before runtime upgrade?

Tags: runtime-upgrade, testing, try-runtime

As the chain state goes larger and larger, it gets hard to export/fetch the chain state.

Are there any other tools aside from [fork-off-substrate](https://github.com/maxsam4/fork-off-substrate) and try-runtime for performing a runtime migration?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "it gets hard to export/fetch the chain state"? 

`try-runtime-cli` has a snapshot feature which allows downloading the state from the node once (slow) and then saving it to disk. Once you have that state on disk, you can use it when calling `on-runtime-upgrade` by passing `snap` instead of `live`, which loads the state almost instantly.

Answer (score 1):

`fork-off-substrate` does not work for large chain state indeed.

The try-runtime CLI got moved into its own repo [try-runtime-cli](https://github.com/paritytech/try-runtime-cli) with documentation linked [here](https://paritytech.github.io/try-runtime-cli/try_runtime/).
We use this regularly in CI and it works well for Polkadot and Kusama. For very large states >10GB it will need some adaptions, so it depends on how large your state currently is.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out try-runtime: https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/tools/use-try-runtime/